# How can i find lines according to some letters place?

Tags: notepad++

I have large sql document.
I don't know how i can find lines which 10th character is "4" or "e" for examle.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to go:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Find what: `^[^4e]{9}[4e]`

Make sure you have checked `Regular expression`